# Establishing a one to many relationship between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relation

I am building a database which consists of a
table of `category, customer table`, and table of product which fetches information from categories.

Now I need a new table for sale which consists of `customerID, date, productID`. My problem is
the customer may buy many products. how can I make the relation between them  in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: I suspect we are missing something here. Do you know what a Foreign Key is?

Comment: yes , i do ,ucan refer to product ID , but that will be only one and customer may buy many items so i neen to refer to severl product ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Customer {id, name, ...}
Product {id, name, ...}
Sale {product_id, customer_id, order_id, qty, ...}
Order {id, date, ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a order table, the order table will keep reference to the products in the order.

Comment: This is a picture of the current  relation  i need sale to support collection of prodcut http://i218.photobucket.com/albums/cc274/gangstaa1603/relation-1.png

Answer (score 1):

Your drawing commented on in @orn's answer only makes sense if each sale can only involve one product.

Mr Fliim put you on the right track to deal with multiple products in one sale.

Comment: thanks , you really opened my eyes i was just readign blind because of the mnay variable in my head i get it now , eah order with one prodcut and all refered to from the new sale ,, thanks all people